# FInd the first unused number in the table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with ID column as interger. I want to get the minimum unused value for this column using function and using WHILE, REPEAT or LOOP.
For example, in this case the unused value is 4

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |

Comment: How did you define unused value? could you explain more detail about that?

Comment: Please post TEST results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for us to know what data you have available.

Answer (score 2):

For min unused in a data-set as given, following can be used -

```
select min(t.id)+1 as min_unused from 
(select id, lead(id) over (order by id)-id gap_id from test) t 
where t.gap_id>1;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0edb912a7edca8726b14bdf430e49e5)

Comment: Wow... That's been a hidden gem all these years 